# Dropdown absolute element is hidden behind row element in table

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm new to react and html/css and I've been trying to create a table where the last column is a dropdown menu with options(currently only one option). The issue I'm running into is that the dropdown menu (set to position: absolute) is masked behind the other rows of the table. [image showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edk7Z.png)

I'm hoping to have the dropdown menu actually dropdown and cover all other elements at least until an option is selected or the menu is closed. Here's what I have so far:

The Component.js

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faArrowLeft,
  faCaretDown,
  faDownload,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getCrsFiles } from "@/pages/api/importsApi";
import { setCrsFiles } from "../importsSlice";

import styles from "./CRSImport.module.css";

const CrsImport = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const files = useSelector((state) => state.imports.crsFiles);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      setCrsFiles([
        { filename: "Some File 1", actionSelected: false },
        { filename: "Some File 2", actionSelected: false },
        { filename: "Some File 3", actionSelected: false },
      ])
    );
  }, []);

  const handleBackButton = () => router.back();

  const handleActionSelected = (i) => () => {
    const selected = { ...files[i], actionSelected: !files[i].actionSelected };

    let newFiles = files.map((x) => ({ ...x, actionSelected: false }));
    newFiles[i] = selected;

    dispatch(setCrsFiles(newFiles));
  };

  const handleMenuItemSelected = (i) => () => {
    handleActionSelected(i)();
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.crsImport}>
      <div className={styles.crsHeader}>
        <div className={styles.backButton} onClick={handleBackButton}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} />
        </div>
        <h4>CRS Import</h4>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.crsBody}>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Filename</th>
              <th>Import Status</th>
              <th>Import Date</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {files.map((x, i) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{x.filename}</td>
                <td>Some Import Status</td>
                <td>Some Import Date</td>
                <td>
                  <div
                    className={`${styles.actions} ${
                      x.actionSelected ? styles.open : ""
                    }`}
                    onClick={handleActionSelected(i)}
                  >
                    <span>Options</span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} />
                  </div>

                  <div
                    className={`${styles.dropdownMenuItems} ${
                      x.actionSelected ? styles.open : ""
                    }`}
                  >
                    <ul>
                      <li onClick={handleMenuItemSelected(i)}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload} />
                        <span>Import</span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrsImport;
```

The module.css

```
.crsImport {
  margin-right: 5rem;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.crsHeader {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: var(--yg__text-color);
  letter-spacing: 0.13rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.backButton {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backButton:active {
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow-inset);
}

.crsBody {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.crsBody table {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-spacing: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.crsBody table thead {
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow-inset);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.crsBody table thead th {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  text-align: start;
  color: #5b5d62;
}

.crsBody table tbody::before {
  content: '';
}

.crsBody table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.crsBody table tbody td {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: var(--yg__text-color);
}

.actions {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 3rem;
  max-width: 8rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.actions.open {
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow-inset);
}

.dropdownMenuItems {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.dropdownMenuItems.open {
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdownMenuItems ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 9rem;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dropdownMenuItems ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.dropdownMenuItems ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: var(--yg__box-shadow-inset);
}

.dropdownMenuItems ul li span {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Any help understanding this would be very much appreciated.